# Curl: don't wait for response

Tags: bash, shell

I currently have a shell script which relies on a curl command like this:

```
curl --request POST -u name:pass -H "Content-Type: application/json"
 --data "{data}" https://url.com --cacert ./my_crt
```

I don't need the response of the command, and this command is in a big for loop, so waiting for the responses take a lot of time.

so, is there a way in bash to do exactly the same thing, but without waiting for the response?

Comment: With curl only - [\[ No \]](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Can_I_use_curl_to_send_a_POST_PU) but who prevents you from doing tricks like what is mentioned in the below answer :-)

Comment: you can use `-m, --max-time <time>` flag to limit operation total time in seconds

Comment: You can use ncat with the --send-only flag to fire post requests without waiting for the response. See https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-other-options.html#ncat-source

Comment: Thanks for the -m recommendation. I am in the same situation as OP (starting a long running process that I don't need the results from in that particular context) and setting -m 1 worked perfect. The call returns almost immediately and the called process runs to completion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a large number of requests you want to issue quickly, and you don't care about the output, there are two things you should do:

1. **Do more requests with the same connection.**

For small requests, it's generally much faster to do 10 requests each on 1 connection, than 1 request each on 10 connections. For [Henry's HTTP post test server](https://posttestserver.com/), the difference is 2.5x:

```
$ time for i in {1..10}; do
    curl -F foo=bar https://posttestserver.com/post.php ;
  done
Successfully dumped 1 post variables.
View it at http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2016/06/09/11.44.48536583865
Post body was 0 chars long.
(...)
real    0m2.429s
```

vs

```
$ time  {
    array=();
    for i in {1..10}; do
      array+=(--next -F foo=bar https://posttestserver.com/post.php ) ; 
    done; 
    curl "${array[@]}";
 }
Successfully dumped 1 post variables.
View it at http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2016/06/09/11.45.461371907842
(...)
real    0m1.079s
```

2. **Process at most a N connections in parallel**, to avoid DoS'ing the host or your machine

Here `sem` from GNU parallel is limiting the number of parallel connections to 4. This is a better version of backgrounding and waiting, since it will always ensure full capacity.

```
for i in {1..20}
do 
  sem -j 4 curl -F foo=bar https://posttestserver.com/post.php
done
sem --wait
```

The number of parallel requests you want depends on how beefy the host is. A realistic number could be 32+

Combine the two strategies, and you should see a hefty speedup without DoS'ing yourself.

Comment: This is a good answer, and will address OP concerns mentioned in a comment in @razz's answer: `I tried it, but, as my loop is pretty big, it froze my computer, and the request didn't worked (I got "couldn't reach host "...")`

Comment: ran into this problem ```/bin/bash: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token: No such file or directory
```

it appears that you need to quote the entirety of the curl command `sem -j 4 'curl ...'`

Comment: had some other problems, like it didn't want to run without multiple inputs, even though I just wanted to run the same command like 20 times concurrently. fixed with this bashism `parallel --jobs 4 -X 'curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" " --silent http://localhost:8080/oauth/token' ::: echo {1..20}`

Answer (score 13):

You could just background it with `&` and to prevent output you can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to to `/dev/null`.

```
curl --request POST -u name:pass -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data "{data}" https://url.com --cacert ./my_crt > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I tried it, but, as my loop is pretty big, it froze my computer,
and the request didn't worked 
(I got "couldn't reach host "...")

Comment: @tuxlu Might consider `wait`ing for all background processes for every N process.

Comment: @tuxlu, I think you might want something like ```while; do for i in $(seq 20); do curl --request POST -u name:pass -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{data}" https://url.com --cacert ./my_crt > /dev/null 2>&1 &; done; wait; done```

this will send 20 `Posts` and then wait, then again, so on and so on untill killed.